# Fetch data with mongoose in ejs template file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I want to fetch all the users in my db inside my ejs file. I have 3 files one model for the data, one ejs file and one js file for my route. The problem is that I don't have any error displaying. I just have an empty list rendered on my browser as if there was no users in the database. Can someone help me?

Here is my route js file :

```
import express from 'express';

import User from "../models/user.js"

const routerUserList = express.Router();

routerUserList.get('/user-list', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const users = User.find({});
    res.render('user-list', {
      pageTitle: 'Liste des utilisateurs',
      path: '/user-list',
      users: users
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({message : "Une erreur est survenue"})
  }
})

export default routerUserList
```

Here is my ejs file :

```
<%- include('./includes/head.ejs') %>
</head>
<body>
  <%- include('./includes/navigation.ejs') %>
  <main>
    <h1>Liste des utilisateurs</h1>
    <% for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {%>
      <li><%= users[i]._id %></li>
      <li><%= users[i].name %></li>
      <li><%= users[i].email %></li>
  <% } %>
  </main>
<%- include('./includes/end.ejs') %>
```

Here is my model file :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  id: {type: String}
})

export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongoose model always returns Promise, you should resolve this promise to get an actual array of users.
Updated code will look like this.

```js
import express from 'express';

import User from "../models/user.js"

const routerUserList = express.Router();

routerUserList.get('/user-list', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res.render('user-list', {
      pageTitle: 'Liste des utilisateurs',
      path: '/user-list',
      users: users
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({message : "Une erreur est survenue"})
  }
})

export default routerUserList
```